# Python tests pass on Gentoo fail on Ubuntu because of locale?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have tests which depend on finding them on the file system with `os.walk`. I suspect that the test fail because of the locale, since `ls` shows different ordering.

Here is `ls` on Gentoo, where tests pass:

```
$ ls test_root/
blogit.db  f.md     post10.md  post12.md  post14.md  post16.md  post18.md  post1.md   post2.md  post4.md  post6.md  post8.md
e.md       page.md  post11.md  post13.md  post15.md  post17.md  post19.md  post20.md  post3.md  post5.md  post7.md  post9.md
```

The locale is `LANG=en_US.utf8`.

Here is `ls` on Ubuntu:

```
$ ls test_root/
blogit.db  f.md     post1.md   post11.md  post13.md  post15.md  post17.md  post19.md  post20.md  post4.md  post6.md  post8.md
e.md       page.md  post10.md  post12.md  post14.md  post16.md  post18.md  post2.md   post3.md   post5.md  post7.md  post9.md
```

If I issue `LANG=C ls` I get the same ordering on Ubuntu. Now I could go and fix my tests, or fix my locale. I thought as a quick solution to run the tests on Ubuntu with:

```
$ LANG=en_US.utf8 py.test tests
```

But this has no effect. Also `LANG=en_US.utf8 ls` does not change the ordering.

So how can I affect `ls` or `os.walk` ordering in Ubuntu?

#### update

Here is how `os.walk` lists the files in Gentoo:

```
In [3]:  for r, d , f in os.walk('test_root'):
    for n in f:
       print n
   ...:       
blogit.db
page.md
post1.md
post2.md
post3.md
... snipped ...
post17.md
post18.md
post19.md
post20.md
```

Here is the same code in Ubuntu:

```
In [6]: for r, d , f in os.walk('test_root'):
    for n in f:
        print(n)
   ...:         

blogit.db
post11.md
page.md
post9.md
post7.md
post3.md
post6.md
post17.md
post20.md
post5.md
post1.md
post2.md
post16.md
post8.md
post12.md
post18.md
post19.md
post10.md
post15.md
post13.md
post4.md
post14.md
```

Comment: You can use the `sorted()` function.

Comment: `ls` uses locale sorting (without `-U`), but `os.walkdir` uses a nondeterministic order.

Comment: Also you should use `LC_ALL` if you want to override locale for testing purposes.

Comment: @o11c, what does it mean? than on each file system or OS `os.walk` will give different results?

Comment: You can change the locale in python but you need to `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"...")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I added the code in the beginning of my tests. It still fails.

Comment: os.walk uses listdir which returns files in an arbitrary order, there is no way outside of sorting to get any consistency across different platforms, what does `ls -U`  output in comparison to os.walk?

Comment: @Oz123 Officially, it's undefined. I have personally noticed: initially, the order is the order the files were created, but if you add many files it becomes quite predictable.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to the hints here, I have decided not to rely on `os.walk` solely, and changed the code from:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CONFIG['content_root']):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(('md', 'markdown')):
```

to:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CONFIG['content_root']):
    for filename in sorted([f for f in files if.endswith(('md', 'markdown'))]):
```

Now all tests passes, regardless to the OS.